# Xamarin.Forms - How to click Back button on Button click

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin.Forms. Now my question is

- I have a Main Page.
- Now and called a Sub Page from that Main Page on
  button click.
- This Sub Page has a form that takes input from user.
- Once user clicks on "Submit" on sub page, I want to return back to
  main page.

So I need to click Back button on "Submit" Button click. So can some one help me to achieve this.

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

display the Sub page as a modal

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SubPage());
```

and then in SubPage, in your button click handler

```
Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by doing the following:

Navigate from Main Page to Sub Page

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new SubPage());
```

Navigate back to Main Page from Sub Page

```
Navigation.PopAsync();
```

More info. can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/)